# Trying to find a song I head about murder for insurance

Tags: indie

Unfortunately, I can't remember the band show sang this song, but if I remember rightly the song was a story about a guy who murdered a girl's husband for insurance money.

I think the story goes something like this:

He saw the bruises on the woman's face
She admitted her husband was beating her
She said he took out a large insurance policy
He said go out of state for a while
He killed the husband
She calls the cops on him
He gets chased by the cops
At the court hearing, it looks like her and the lawyer were "up all night"
He gets sent down for life

I'm hoping I gave enough detail there for someone to identify the song.

Comment: "She was married when we first met. Soon to be divorced. I helped her out of a jam, I guess. But I used a little too much force." :D

Comment: do you remember roughly when you heard this ?  anything distinctive about the singer's voice, the backing etc ?

Comment: It was mainly acoustic guitar being played. The singer was a bloke, and he sang in quite a soft voice... this was probably about 6 or 7 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Tattoo of your name by Vast